# ajax toolkit controls grayed out due to designer compatability or framework

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have converted my project from visual studio 2005 to Visual studio 2012. I am using.Net frmawork version 4.5.and i want to add ajax control toolkit in my project.i have created new control with named ajax and add items from browsing ajax toolkit 4.5.after clicking ok popup is displayed showing controls are added sucessfully but make sure framework version and design compatability.please give me a solution.i have tried all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this issue,Goto property pages and in build option select appropriate version on ajax control toolkit